# Guice generics - how can I make it less ugly?

Tags: java, generics, coding-style, guice

I have an interface `Producer<T>` and a concrete `FooProducer` that implements `Producer<Foo>`. Binding this in guice looks ugly as sin:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Producer<Foo>>() {}).to(FooProducer.class);
```

I have lots of these such bindings. I have tried the following:

```
static <T> TypeLiteral<Producer<T>> producer() {
    return new TypeLiteral<Producer<T>>(){};
}
```

With calls made in this way:

```
bind(ContainingClass.<Foo>producer()).to(FooProducer.class);
```

But it gives an error along the lines of `Producer<T> is not specific enough...`.

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Producer<Foo>>() {}).to(FooProducer.class);
```

try a convenience method like

```
static <T> Key<Producer<T>> producerOf(Class<T> type) {
  return (Key<Producer<T>>)Key.get(Types.newParameterizedType(Producer.class,type));
}
```

and then in your module

```
bind(producerOf(Foo.class)).to(FooProducer.class);
```

That unchecked cast should be safe.  Key is com.google.inject.Key and Types is com.google.inject.util.Types.

good luck

Comment: This works in this simple case but doesn't if you want, say, `Producer<List<Foo>>`. Overall it seems like a waste of effort, especially when you have to make a method like this for every parameterized type you want to use, but whatever floats the OP's boat I guess.

Answer (score 7):

You can save 8 characters by typing `new Key<Producer<Foo>>(){}` rather than `new TypeLiteral<Producer<Foo>>(){}`. Or by using the equivalent @Provides method:

```
@Provides
public Producer<Foo> provideFooProducer(FooProducer fooProducer) {
  return fooProducer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that due to how `TypeLiteral`s work, you have to actually write `new TypeLiteral<Producer<Foo>>(){}` or the necessary type information will not be available. They utilize the fact that a class that has fully specified its generic types can have information on those types retrieved. When you write `new TypeLiteral<Producer<T>>(){}`, you aren't specifying what `T` is, so that information isn't available.

It's subjective, but I don't think creating a type literal looks too ugly, considering what it does.

As an aside, I don't know what your `Producer` interface does, but *if* it is just used for producing instances of `T` (with a method that takes no arguments), you could use Guice's `Provider` interface instead. Then you just have to do:

```
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class);
```

And you can inject a `Foo` or a `Provider<Foo>` anywhere.

Comment: That's quite interesting I hadn't thought about it that way. My `Producer` interface does a number of other things also, but I will keep this approach in mind for the future. Thanks.

Comment: The `@Provides` method that Jesse mentions in his answer is equivalent to writing a custom `Provider` implementation as well, and a lot easier.

Comment: `@Provides` annotation is supposed to be used every time one provides an implementation binding for some type. It entails method declaration and finally leads to unnecessary verbosity. Consider how much we save in case of just two types:  
`bind(producerOf(Foo.class)).to(FooProducer.class);
    bind(producerOf(Bar.class)).to(BarProducer.class);`
against  
`@Provides public Producer<Foo> provideFooProducer(FooProducer fooProducer) { return fooProducer; }
    @Provides public Producer<Bar> provideBarProducer(BarProducer barProducer) { return barProducer; }`